# Function with multiple column input query in PostgreSQL not working

Tags: postgresql

```
create or replace function help_index(t_nspname text, t_tablename text) 
  returns table(index_id text,is_disabled text,index_name text, index_description text, index_keys text, included_columns text, filter_definition text,columns_in_tree text,columns_in_leaf text,index_type text)
as 
$body$
SELECT
  null::text as index_id,
  null::text as is_disabled,
  i.relname::text AS index_name,
  null::text as  index_description,
       ARRAY(
           SELECT pg_get_indexdef(idx.indexrelid, k + 1, TRUE)
           FROM
             generate_subscripts(idx.indkey, 1) AS k
           ORDER BY k
       ) AS index_keys,
  null::text as included_columns,
  null::text as filter_definiton,
ARRAY(
           SELECT pg_get_indexdef(idx.indexrelid, k + 1, TRUE)
           FROM
             generate_subscripts(idx.indkey, 1) AS k
           ORDER BY k
       ) AS columns_in_tree,
ARRAY(
           SELECT pg_get_indexdef(idx.indexrelid, k + 1, TRUE)
           FROM
             generate_subscripts(idx.indkey, 1) AS k
           ORDER BY k
       ) AS columns_in_leaf,
  am.amname                AS index_type
FROM pg_index AS idx
  JOIN pg_class AS i
    ON i.oid = idx.indexrelid
  JOIN pg_am AS am
    ON i.relam = am.oid
  JOIN pg_namespace AS NS ON i.relnamespace = NS.OID
  JOIN pg_user AS U ON i.relowner = U.usesysid
WHERE NOT nspname LIKE 'pg%' -- Excluding system tables
AND ns.nspname=t_nspname
AND i.relname=t_tablename;
$body$
language sql;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "leaf"
LINE 1: leaf text,index_type text)

Now got this error..looks like need to add typecast for index_keys 5th column but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL functions are a bit more picky about data types than "regular SQL".

If you look at the [definition of `pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html) you will see that `relname` is defined as type `name`, not `text`.

The error message

> ```
> Final statement returns name instead of text at column 3.
> ```

is telling you exactly that. So you need to cast that column to text:

```
i.relname::text AS index_name,
```

The same is true for the column 10 `am.amname`

---

**Edit** after the question was changed.

The new error message tells you (again), exactly what your problem is:

> ```
> Final statement returns text[] instead of text at column 5.
> ```

The select expression for column 5 (and 6) is:

```
 ARRAY( ... )
```

So that returns an array, not a string (text).

As you you seem to want to get a list of columns for that index not an array,  you need to use `string_agg()`:

```
  (select string_agg(pg_get_indexdef(idx.indexrelid, colidx + 1, true), ',')
   from generate_subscripts(idx.indkey,1) as t(colidx)) as index_keys,
```

Your condition `i.relname=t_tablename` is also wrong as `i.relname` is the name of the index, not the name of the table you want to get the indexes for.

You need to change the joins to something like this:

```
FROM pg_index AS idx
  JOIN pg_class AS i
    ON i.oid = idx.indexrelid
  JOIN pg_am AS am
    ON i.relam = am.oid
  JOIN pg_user AS U ON i.relowner = U.usesysid
  JOIN pg_class AS tbl on tbl.oid = idx.indrelid --<< here
  JOIN pg_namespace AS ns ON tbl.relnamespace = ns.oid --<< here
```

Putting all that together, the following should do what you want:

```
create or replace function help_index(t_nspname text, t_tablename text) 
  returns table(index_id text,is_disabled text,index_name text, index_description text, index_keys text, included_columns text, filter_definition text,columns_in_tree text,columns_in_leaf text,index_type text)
as 
$body$
SELECT
    null::text as index_id,
    null::text as is_disabled,
    i.relname::text AS index_name,
    null::text as  index_description,
    (select string_agg(pg_get_indexdef(idx.indexrelid, colidx + 1, true), ',')
     from generate_subscripts(idx.indkey,1) as t(colidx)) as index_keys,
    null::text as included_columns,
    null::text as filter_definiton,
    (select string_agg(pg_get_indexdef(idx.indexrelid, colidx + 1, true), ',')
     from generate_subscripts(idx.indkey,1) as t(colidx)) as columns_in_tree,
    (select string_agg(pg_get_indexdef(idx.indexrelid, colidx + 1, true), ',')
     from generate_subscripts(idx.indkey,1) as t(colidx)) as columns_in_leaf,
    am.amname::text                AS index_type
FROM pg_index AS idx
  JOIN pg_class AS i
    ON i.oid = idx.indexrelid
  JOIN pg_am AS am
    ON i.relam = am.oid
  JOIN pg_user AS U ON i.relowner = U.usesysid
  JOIN pg_class AS tbl on tbl.oid = idx.indrelid
  JOIN pg_namespace AS ns ON tbl.relnamespace = ns.oid
WHERE NOT nspname LIKE 'pg%' -- Excluding system tables
  AND ns.nspname = t_nspname
  AND tbl.relname = t_tablename;
$body$
language sql;
```

Comment: @rock_techie: note that with the upcoming v11 you could populate `included_columns` because including "non-key" columns will be supported in that version